# Merge a branch from another branch in master

Tags: git, pull-request

[image: Workflow]

**Following this picture:**

- I create a branch from master (Branch 1)
- I push 3 commits.
- I create a pull request on master.
- Instead of waiting the branch 1 to be merged in master, I create a branch 2 from the branch 1.
- I push 3 commits, meanwhile the branch 1 as been merged in master with the pull request.
- I create a pull request for branch 2.

**My questions are:**

- In my 2nd pull request, will l have only the 3 commits of the branch 2 or the 6 commits of the branch 1 and 2 ? Indeed, given that the branch 1 has been merged in master its 3 commits are no longer new in branch 2.
- Same questions for the files changed in branch 1, will they appear in the pull request of the branch 2 even if the branch 1 has been merged in master ?

Hope this is clear enough. Thanks

Comment: Btw, your graph is probably as cute as low tech. Loved it. :'-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before the first pull request had been merged in `master`, the second one featured all commits unknown to `master`, so yes, all commits of `branch1` and `branch2`.

But now that branch1 is merged into master, **the second pull request will only bring the last three commits**, those yet unknown to `branch1` and `master`.

So to conclude, if your fear was that you're bringing the same commits twice : no, it won't happen, you're good as it is.